# Module Error (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)

Tags: css, node.js, angular, sass, compiler-errors

[image]

[image]

> ERROR in ./src/scss/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/scss/styles.scss)
>   Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js):
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectA\postGrad-Frontend\src\scss\pages\login.scss:6:13: Can't resolve '../../assets/images/login-bg.jpg' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\projectA\postGrad-Frontend\src\scss'

Why it is throwing an error.
the correct image present in my images.
I tried rebuilding the `npm rebuild` but no luck.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just added single slash `/` in my `background:url(/../../assets)` and its working as expected as per documentation it means it will look from the `current path.`

Comment: It worked, although why it is working? Both Scss and HTML files are in the same folder, so they should work with the same pointing route to the assets. (yes the path is working in the HTML file)

Comment: with the slash it compiles, but I obtain a HTTP 404 in the frontend because it searches the resources outside the context root. What can I do in this case? (Angular 12)

Answer (score 9):

Replace path from this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Effra';
  src: url('assets/fonts/Effra_W_It.ttf') format("truetype");
  font-weight:400;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

**To this:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Effra';
  src: url("~assets/fonts/Effra_W_It.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight:400;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

The change in the path to file is key:
**~assets/**

Answer (score 5):

I received similar error while building an Angular CLI application after upgrading the application from Angular 8 to Angular 10. A component was using an scss file that had a path to an image in the `assets` folder (e.g. `assets/images/test.jpg`). This path to the image worked in Angular 8 (e.g. `assets/images/test.jpg`) but did not work after the upgrade. The build will break with the following error as it was looking for the image file relative to the current directory the component was in. The file would not display on the page also. I changed the path relative to the component's folder such as `../../../../assets/images/test.jpg` that resolved the issue.

Error: `(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\myproject\my.component.scss:10:12: Can't resolve './assets/images/test.jpg'`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add `/` to the beginning of the path:
example: `/assets/images/bg-1.png` where assets are located in the root under src Folder